# Flutter : align icon to the middle -- bottom navigation bar

Tags: flutter

I have a bottom nav bar in my flutter app. How do I align the icon to the middle . Currently , it seems to be top align

```
Widget _bottomNavigationBar(int selectedIndex) {
    return BottomNavigationBar(
      backgroundColor: Palette.YELLOW,
      onTap: (int index) {
        setState(() {
          userModel.selectedIndex = index;
        });
      },
      currentIndex: userModel.selectedIndex,
      items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Image.asset(
            "assets/images/search_nav_icon.png",

          ),
          title: Text(''),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Image.asset(
              "assets/images/fav_nav_icon.png",

            ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap each Icon with a `Container` and set it's `alignment` property to `Alignment.center`.

Now wrap each `Container` with a `Expanded` widget and group them horizontally with the help of a Row Widget.

```
 Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: <Widget> [
    Expanded(child: Container(alignment:Alignment.center,child: Icon([...]),),),
    Expanded(child: Container(alignment:Alignment.center,child: Icon([...]),),),
    Expanded(child: Container(alignment:Alignment.center,child: Icon([...]),),)
  ]
)
```

You can increase/decrease the number of `Expanded` widgets as per your convenience, but make sure that you don't wrap any other single-child widget over `Expanded` widget

Comment: Whrer we need to use this row with BottomNavigationBar ?

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me. I have labels as well

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me when Icons are used and no Text.

return BottomNavigationBar(
      showSelectedLabels: false,
      showUnselectedLabel: false,
      // ...
);

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution is in **BottomNavigationBar** use below properties:

```
 showSelectedLabels: false,
 showUnselectedLabels: true,
```

Answer (score 0):

If u want a full flexibility you can create your own **bottomNavigationBar**
This was my approach months ago

```
bottomNavigationBar: Container(
  color: primary,
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
  child: Row(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center, // Optional
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly, // Change to your own spacing
    children: [
      Text("SHOPS"), //REPLACE WITH ICON
      Text("ORDERS"), //REPLACE WITH ICON
    ],
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

use one of these properties inside bottom navigation bar

`landscapeLayout: BottomNavigationBarLandscapeLayout.spread`

`landscapeLayout: BottomNavigationBarLandscapeLayout.centered`

`landscapeLayout: BottomNavigationBarLandscapeLayout.linear`

Use "spread" property for your obstacle

Answer (score -1):

One easy solution is - Wrap BottomNavigationBar widget with Column.
And set `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center`

```
return Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: <Widget> [
    BottomNavigationBar(...)
  ]
);
```

There must be have better way to do this, but i found this technique very helpful.